Expectation Value of Observable from evolved statevectors using qiskit on Hardware
I want to compute this <Zi Zj> - <Zi><Zj> for an entangled n-qubit initial state under the application of a general XY Hamiltonian for a range of time 0 to T. This is to be done to study how the correlations between the qubits decay over time. This quantity should be plotted <Zi Zj> - <Zi><Zj> as a function of time from 0 to T.
Hamiltonian Code
def get_hamiltonian(params, **kwargs):
    '''
    Returns a general XY Hamiltonian.
    '''
    ## Extract parameters
    L, alpha, J = params['L'], params['alpha'], params['J']
    
    ### Define the XX and YY tuples with corrected list comprehension
    XX_tuples = [("XX", [i, j], -J / np.power(np.abs(i - j), alpha)) for i in range(L - 1) for j in range(i + 1, L)]
    YY_tuples = [("YY", [i, j], -J / np.power(np.abs(i - j), alpha)) for i in range(L - 1) for j in range(i + 1, L)]
    
    # Combine the tuples to create the Hamiltonian
    hamiltonian = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list([*XX_tuples, *YY_tuples], num_qubits=L)
    return hamiltonian.simplify()

N-qubit Entangled State
def get_qc_for_n_qubit_GHZ_state(params, **kwargs):
    """This function will create a qiskit.QuantumCircuit (qc) for an n-qubit GHZ state.
 
    Args:
        params - only requires 'L' parameter to construct Q.circuit and entangled state.
 
    Returns:
        QuantumCircuit: Quantum circuit that generate the n-qubit GHZ state, assuming all qubits start in the 0 state
        Entangled n-qubit GHZ state
    """
    n = params['L']
    initial_state = '0' * n
    sv1 = Statevector.from_label(initial_state)
    if isinstance(n, int) and n >= 2:
        qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
        qc.h(0)
        for i in range(n-1):
            qc.cx(i, i+1)
    else:
        raise Exception("n is not a valid input")
    new_sv1 = sv1.evolve(qc)
    return qc, new_sv1

Observables Construction
def observables_construction(params, **kwargs):
    '''
    Returns the list of observables
    '''
    L = params['L']
    Z_op = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list(
        [("Z", [i], 1.0) for i in range(0, L)], num_qubits=L
    )
    correlation_op = SparsePauliOp.from_sparse_list(
        [("ZZ", [i, j], 1.0) for i in range(0, L - 1) for j in range(i+1, L)], num_qubits=L
    )
    return Z_op, correlation_op

Part-I
Using Qiskit Trotterization Algorithm to study <Zi Zj> - <Zi><Zj> as a function of time
params['T'] = 40.0
params['L'] = 5
params['time_step'] = 60
## Assigning Hamiltonian and Observables
H = get_hamiltonian(params)
Z_op, correlation_op = observables_construction(params)
GHZ_qc, initial_state = get_qc_for_n_qubit_GHZ_state(params)

## Defining Time Evolution Problem
problem = TimeEvolutionProblem(
    H,
    initial_state=initial_state,
    time=params['T'],
    aux_operators=[Z_op, correlation_op],
)

## Performing Trotterization
trotter = TrotterQRTE(num_timesteps=params['time_step'], estimator=Estimator())
result = trotter.evolve(problem)

## Extracting results of the observables
observables = np.array(np.array(result.observables)[:, :, 0])
observables.shape 

Plotting Data
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
times = np.linspace(0, params['T'], params['time_step'] + 1)  # includes initial state
axes[0].plot(
    times, observables[:, 0], label="First order", marker="x", c="darkmagenta", ls="-", lw=0.8
)
axes[1].plot(
    times, np.round(observables[:, 1].astype(float), decimals = 3), label="First order", marker="x", c="darkmagenta", ls="-", lw=0.8
)
axes[0].set_ylabel(f"$<Z_i>$")
axes[1].set_ylabel(f"$<Z_iZ_j>$")
axes[1].set_xlabel("Time")
fig.suptitle("Observable evolution")

Packages used in Part-1
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from math import sin, cos, pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit_algorithms import TimeEvolutionProblem
from qiskit_algorithms import TrotterQRTE
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator 
import scipy as sc
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliEvolutionGate
from qiskit.synthesis import LieTrotter
from qiskit.synthesis import SuzukiTrotter
from qiskit.synthesis import SuzukiTrotter
from matplotlib import cm

Queries in Part-1
The expectation values of <Z_i> are coming out to be zero. And I guess the data I obtain for these two sets of observables <Zi Zj> and <Z_i> are the summation over all possible combinations for each time step. So, I am unable to compute the required quantity <Zi Zj> - <Zi><Zj>. Could somebody please tell me how to obtain this quantity?
Part-II: Execution on Real Hardware
Part-I is only for testing purposes before running on real hardware.
Initial Set-up
params['T'] = 40.0
params['L'] = 5
params['time_step'] = 60
## Assigning Hamiltonian and Observables
H = get_hamiltonian(params)
Z_op, correlation_op = observables_construction(params)
GHZ_qc, initial_state = get_qc_for_n_qubit_GHZ_state(params)

Optimizing the Problem
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum", token=IBM_API)
 
backend = service.least_busy(simulator=False, operational=True, min_num_qubits=params['L'])
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
 
isa_circuit = pm.run(GHZ_qc)
isa_operators_list = [op.apply_layout(isa_circuit.layout) for op in correlation_op]

Execution on Hardware
options = EstimatorOptions()
options.resilience_level = 1
estimator = Estimator(backend, options=options)

## Submit the circuit to Estimator
job = estimator.run([(isa_circuit, isa_operators_list)])
job_id = job.job_id()
print(job_id)

Intrepreting Results
result = job.result()[0]
values = result.data.evs

Queries in Part-2
I am not able to understand the hardware results are with respect to which quantity (for eg, with respect to time). In case they are not with respect to time, what must be done to obtain the quantity <Zi Zj> - <Zi><Zj> as a function of time?

There seems to be some issues with your pasted code (in the last lines of the first two cells at least), can you please fix them? Also, can you paste the entirety of your code so that we can test it? In particular, it seems like you're using the Estimator from qiskit-ibm-runtime but I'd like to be sure :)

@TristanNemoz yes, I am using Estimator from qiskit-ibm-runtime. I've made the changes. Thanks.

You say it is giving you the incorrect value saying that "it should be less than 1". However, Given the input state and Hamiltonian you have, the exp vals for $XI$,
$IX$ and $XX$ will always be $0$, $0$ and $1$ independent of time, which seems to align with your observation.

@diemilio Why is it independent of time? exp(-i * t X1X2 + Y1Y2) |psi> --> gives |psi> for t = 0. Non-zero 't' values, exp(-i * t X1X2 + Y1Y2) |psi> --> some other basis state orthogonal to |psi> for this particular case (|01>+|10>)/2.

Also, I noticed that with observable as XiXj - it's expectation value with respect to the entangled qubits would always be zero, is that correct? However, using ZiZj as observable it serves the purpose ig. I want to understand how the correlation of two entangled qubits change over time under the XY Hamiltonian.

@CuriousMind, I posted it as an answer but lmk if you have questions and I will modify it.

The reason you don't see changes in the expectation values as you change $t$ is because they are independent of time. Here's why.
You defined the following Hamiltonian:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
H &= XX + YY
\\
\\ 
H &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
H &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
H &= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
This results in the following time-evolution unitary:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
U(t) = & \; e^{-iHt}
\\
\\
U(t) = & \; \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{e^{2 i t} + e^{-2 i t}}{2} & \frac{-e^{2 i t} + e^{-2 i t}}{2} & 0\\0 & \frac{-e^{2 i t} + e^{-2 i t}}{2} & \frac{e^{2 i t} + e^{-2 i t}}{2} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\
\\
U(t) = & \; \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(2t) & -i\sin(2t) & 0\\0 & -i\sin(2t) & \cos(2t) & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since you initialized the following state:
$$ |\psi(0)\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|01\rangle + |10\rangle \right), $$
when you evolve that state through $U(t)$ you get:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|\psi(t)\rangle &= U(t) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|01\rangle + |10\rangle \right) \right)
\\
\\
|\psi(t)\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\cos(2t)|01\rangle -i\sin(2t)|10\rangle - i\sin(2t)|01\rangle + \cos(2t)|10\rangle \right)
\\
\\
|\psi(t)\rangle &= \frac{e^{-2it}}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|01\rangle +|10\rangle \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
So the time $t$ ends up being simply a component of the global phase of the state making any expectation value independent of $t$.

does it mean entanglement of two qubits is always preserved under the XY Hamiltonian? I tried now with 3 entangled qubits, GHZ State - the correlation function  fluctuates from 0 to 3, and the max value is 3 at t = 0. Is this a correct observation? I expected it to go zero for large time.

For 2 entangled qubits, as you can see from the unitary expression above, it is independent of t. For an n-qubit GHZ state I would have expected to be independent of t too though. You might need to share a simple 3 qubit example to see if there are issues with the code. However, your post is getting a bit messy because you are changing the question quite a bit. Maybe share a simple toy example like the one you have for 2 qubits but generalized for n qubits so it is easy for others to check your code. Sharing your full code might not be beneficial bc there's too much to look at.

sorry for the confusion. I organized the post and specified the queries I have. I guess they are not constant for more than 2 qubits, since the XY Hamiltonian I am considering is a general one and has long-range interactions too. $H = \sum_{i<j} (X_iX_j + Y_iY_j)/ | i - j |^\alpha $.
